# i want to find control and add dynamic control to page derived from master page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried this code but not able to complete the task, please to help!

```
public void data()
        {
            string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalMySqlServer"].ConnectionString;
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {

                con.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from movie;", con);

                MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (dr.HasRows)
                {

                    Control abc = this.FindControl("divv");

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        if (abc != null)
                        {
                            Label lbl = new Label();

                            abc.Controls.Add(lbl);

                            lbl.Text = dr["mv_title"].ToString();
                            //abc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where is code??

Comment: change your query to select mv_title from movie

Comment: what do youe mean by this ? code but not able to complete the task

Comment: what should i change?

Comment: you should explain what error are you getting? in which line??

Comment: object reference not found >

Comment: in abc.Controls.Add(lbl)

Comment: you shoud write this line. lbl.Text = dr["mv_title"].ToString();abc.Controls.Add(lbl);

Comment: I doubt , you again check is this the correct line ?

Comment: THIS IS THE SAME LINE I HAVE TRIED! SEE ABOVE

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and notify the error.I will comment the answer using datareader also.Sorry for the funny comment.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
sda.Fill(ds);
Control abc = this.FindControl("divv");
Label lbl = new Label();
abc.Controls.Add(lbl);
lbl.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["mv_title"].ToString();
con.close();
```

Comment: the data is not displayed

Comment: the blank page is coming

Comment: This is comment now answer

Comment: what do you mean ??

Comment: WHAT SHOULD I USE INSTEAD OF DATASET IN MYSQL DATABASE

Comment: SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
               while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                         Control abc = this.FindControl("Form1");
                         Label lbl = new Label();
                         abc.Controls.Add(lbl);
                         lbl.Text = sdr["title"].ToString();
                    }

Comment: actually your code is right bro,try without abc!=null condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm done by trying the following code

```
Control content = Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

Control abc = content.FindControl("divv");
```